# Two dogs barking independently uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Two dogs are in front of your house. The first barking of the two dogs are independent of each other, and may occur at any time uniformly within 4 seconds after opening the door, and then each dog barks at an interval of 4 seconds. If the two dogs both notice you opening the door at the same time, what is the probability that the difference between their first barking moments is no more than 2 seconds?

$f(x) = \int probability(>) , 0<x<4 $

i know that the uniform distribution is bounded by 0 and 4,

but i do not know what to do to go further from this question

Honestly very lost and do not know where to start

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: I believe uniformly means the uniform distribution

Comment: @saulspatz i basically couldnt really touch the question hence wanted some steps and solution to the foundations of the answering

Comment: Hint: draw a picture of the probability space.  Describe the "good" region.

Comment: Yes, uniformly means the uniform distribution.  You need to think about the product probability.  If the times the dogs start barking are $X$ and $Y$, then $(X,Y)$ lies in the square $0\leq X,Y\leq4$.  What region of the square corresponds to the case where the dogs start barking within $2$ seconds of one another?  How does the area of that region compare to the area of the square?

Comment: I just want to say how much I love questions that have things like "dogs barking" in the title. They convey something special about the place of mathematics in the world.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint, which may help

[image]

Comment: could i get some explainations

Comment: @jixubi I would suggest considering whet the axes represent.  Similarly the red lines and the areas.  If that does not help, then try a different approach

Answer (score 1):

They are requesting you to calculate the following probability

$$\mathbb{P}[|X-Y|<2]$$

doing a drawing of the situation you get that the "good" region is the purple one

[image]

Of course it is easier to calculate the complement probability, thus

$$\mathbb{P}[|X-Y|<2]=1-\frac{4}{16}=\frac{3}{4}$$